# ¿Como utilizar un mismo virtualenv (python) en Windows y Linux?

Tags: python, linux, windows

Comencé a utilizar recientemente Windows y Linux en una misma pc (instalados en distintas particiones respectivamente y una tercera para archivos en común) pero resulta que los entornos creados en Windows se generan con la carpeta "Scripts", y en Linux el equivalente sería la carpeta "bin".
El problema aquí es que los archivos de estas carpetas no son compatibles para ambos SO. por ejemplo, "activate" contenido en bin(creados en Linux) no se puede ejecutar en Windows, y viceversa, el "activate" de Scripts(creados en Windows) no corre en Linux.

¿Como se puede hacer para trabajar en un mismo virtualenv desde ambos SO?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No se puede tal como lo planteas. Pero lo que necesitas comprender es que el entorno lo recreas en cada sistema operativo. Es el mismo porque te ofrece las mismas capacidades, pero desde la perspectiva de cada sistema operativo.

Mira, cuando digo que se recrea es porque ambos cumplen con los mismos requisitos. Cuando haces `pip freeze` logras que el entorno que usas en un SO se pueda usar en cualquier otro... pero ojo, hablamos del **entorno** no de los archivos binarios específicos.

De hecho, hay muy pocos módulos de Python que solo se pueden usar en *nix... ahora mismo solo recuerdo la librería `readline` que no se puede usar en Windows, aunque hay alternativas. Y, por supuesto, los drivers que son enlazados con librerías binarias.

### El archivo de requisitos

La clave para replicar un entorno virtual es el archivo de requisitos. Este, es un simple archivo de texto que contiene **todos** los paquetes instalados en el entorno de trabajo actual (pensemos siempre en entornos virtuales). Se crea de forma muy simple, ejecutando esta orden

```
$ pip freeze --local > requisitos.txt
```

Como ya se explicó, contiene los paquetes e indica la versión instalada. Un archivo de requisitos se ve así:

```
dj-database-url==0.4.1
Django==1.10.3
django-allauth==0.28.0
django-braces==1.10.0
django-configurations==2.0
django-coverage-plugin==1.3.1
django-crispy-forms==1.6.1
django-debug-toolbar==1.6
django-environ==0.4.0
```

El objetivo de este archivo es replicar el entorno de de trabajo/producción en cualquier sistema, **cualquiera que este sea**.

#### Cómo funciona

Lo que sucede es es que un entorno virtual es un conjunto de configuraciones y variables de entorno que aíslan un ejecutable de Python para que solo busque e instale paquetes en un directorio particular y, a menos que así se indique, **ignore los paquetes instalados en el sistema**.

De este modo, puedo tener un entorno virtual que use Django 1.6 y otro que use Django 1.10 en el mismo sistema operativo y solo tengo que activar con el que desee trabajar.

Y funciona también en el caso que planteas. Cuando estás en Windows creas un entorno virtual que instala los paquetes en, digamos, `%appdata%`. Cuando creas un entorno virtual en Linux, usa el directorio `~/.virtualenv/`, por ejemplo.

Entonces, en cualquiera de tus dos sistemas solo tienes que hacer:

```
pip install -r requisitos.txt
```

y `pip` se encargará de buscar, descargar, instalar y configurar los módulos indicados.

Con el entorno activado, puedes trabajar con tu proyecto en donde se encuentre. Digamos que en Windows trabajas en `d:/proyectos/compartido` y en linux en `/opt/proyectos/compartido`. Dado que los archivos son los mismos, solo tienes que activar el entorno virtual para hacerlo funcionar.

> #### Importante
>
> Dado que la clave es el archivo re requisitos, es **muy importante** que recuerdes actualizarlo cada vez que instales o actualices un paquete. **No importa el sistema en el que lo hagas**, pero siempre recuerda ejecutar `pip install -r ...` en el otro.

En este sentido, no te vendría usar un control de versiones como **Git** para un mejor control de tu proyecto.

---

#### Conclusión

En resumen: no puedes y no debes usar *los mismos directorios*. Afortunadamente, los entornos virtuales se pueden reproducir y funcionan de manera prácticamente igual en cualquier sistema operativo.

#### Alternativa

Puedes usar Vagrant. Configurado correctamente, puedes especificar la ruta del guest y en el caso que presentas, el guest puede ser el mismo para ambos sistemas host. Y la imagen puede estar en tu tercera partición.

Comment: Hola toledano! entiendo el planteo, puedo recrear EV's identicos en ambos SO. El problema con ello es que cuando trabaje en el de Linux por ej, todo lo que allí haga no lo podré utilizar desde Windows y viceversa. Tendría que hacer el trabajo por separado para ambos EV's.

Comment: Ojalá exista alguna posibilidad directa para lograr esto. Caso contrario tendré que ponerme a ver Vagrant. Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Pues por un lado son, efectivamente, dos sistemas diferentes. Pero mira, Muchos crean el entorno virtual en el directorio de su proyecto. __No lo hagas__. Los archivos de tu proyecto son compartidos, pero cada SO tendrá el entorno virtual con todo lo necesario para funcionar. Es decir, lo que comentas, en realidad no pasa. O no funciona como tú piensas.

Comment: Creo que estás olvidando el archivo de requisitos. En un rato más actualizo la respuesta para aclarar el uso de `pip`.

Comment: Disculpa pero no termino de comprender. Según lo que comentas sería posible por ejemplo: ¿trabajar en un archivo "models.py" desde Windows y luego seguir trabajando en el mismo archivo pero desde Linux?

Comment: Si, y más aún, si trabajas con una base SQLite, incluso los datos serían los mismos.

Comment: Que bueno esto que me dices!! creo que entendí. Por ej una forma podría ser en un mismo directorio crear un EV desde Windows, luego desde Linux,(con ambos requirements por igual) y poder trabajar en este proyecto desde ambos SO.  O bien que los archivos del proyecto estén en un 3er directorio fuera de los venvs creados para este y luego trabajar allí habiendo activado cualquiera de ambos.

Comment: Actualizada la respuesta. Si te sirvió, recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada. ¡Nos dan puntos!

Comment: Clarisimo y completo... gracias!!!